# If I declare a variable in a function in Python, does it get calculated everytime I call it?

Tags: python

For example, I need this variable, which is a list of prime numbers. If I put it inside a function (that runs over 5000 times) the overall runtime is slower (3 - 4 seconds). If I use `global` instead, the script runs in less than 1 second (everyone says using `global` is bad though). What happens? I'm new to Python sorry!

```
primes = sorted([x for x in range(1, 10000) if is_prime(x)])
```

Comment: Your function does whatever you tell it to, each time you call it - if you tell it to make a list of prime numbers then that's what it does.

Comment: You could determine the list in the function that calls the function (that runs over 5000 times), then pass it in.

Comment: @Amiga500: the outer one  (caller) runs just once, presumably

Comment: As a side note, there are much more efficient ways to generate all primes below 10000 than testing all numbers below 10000. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n

Comment: @Sergio - I'd think we could assume at some point there is a level where its ran just once, even if that's right up in main(). But obviously passing from main() through several tiers to get to foo() could be a right bollox. Hence my hack answer I've put up. Not great practice, but useful for digging yourself out of a hole.

Comment: @Amiga500 my comment was to clarify the original wording of your comment. It seemed ambiguous (to me, at least)

Comment: Your not wrong - it was ambiguous!

Answer (score 0):

Globals are bad. But sometimes they are a far simpler and more expedient solution than the alternative.

As a guard against inadvertent changes to globals, this is what I've been using for some time.

I'd make a separate .py, for instance myGlobalVariables.py and within it I'd have code like:

```
def setGlobalPrimes(primesIn):
    global globalPrimes
    globalPrimes = primesIn
```

Then, from within my main code, I'd

```
import myGlobalVariables

def foo():  #foo that runs 5000 times
    primes = myGlobalVariables.globalPrimes

    #calcs & stuff here

    return answers


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    #prime all globals
    myGlobalVariables.setGlobalPrimes(sorted([x for x in range(1, 10000) if is_prime(x)]))
    

    #Then whatever you have in your code (obviously below is just me being silly)
    for i in range(0, 5000):            
        foo()
```

Basically, it makes the chances of you inadvertently updating/overwriting a global much harder. You can of course do it by:

```
myGlobalVariables.globalPrimes = [blah blah]
```

It stops you doing so many re-calcs, thus speeding up your code a bit.